# Oracle SQL query/Procedure to list Months/Quarters between two dates

Tags: sql, oracle

I have one requirement

```
START_DATE : 03/01/2018
END_DATE : 28/12/2018
```

I need a query which will list all the months starting date and end date between these two dates like this

```
StartMonth   EndMonth
03/01/2018  31/01/2018
01/02/2018  28/01/2018
01/03/2018  31/03/2018
01/04/2018  30/04/2018
01/05/2018  31/05/2018
01/06/2018  30/06/2018
01/07/2018  31/07/2018
01/08/2018  31/08/2018
01/09/2018  30/09/2018
01/10/2018  31/10/2018
01/11/2018  30/11/2018
01/12/2018  28/12/2018
```

I also need a query which will list all the Quarter's starting date and end date between these two dates like this

```
StartQuarter EndQuarter
03/01/2018   31/03/2018
01/04/2018   30/06/2018
01/07/2018   30/09/2018
01/10/2018   28/12/2018
```

Comment: SQL only or can you use PL/SQL?

Comment: PL/SQL also fine

Comment: Do you have any reasonable limit on the number of intervals you'd expect to get back?

Comment: Limit is there..Usually 1-3 years..But it could be more..So i would like to get a solution which will not limit it to smaller timeframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These should work.

For months:

```
    select greatest(:start_date, trunc(add_months( :start_date, level - 1), 'MON')) as startmonth,
           least(:end_date, last_day(add_months( :start_date, level - 1))) as endmonth
      from dual
connect by level <= trunc(months_between(trunc( :end_date, 'MON'), trunc( :start_date, 'MON'))) + 1;
```

For quarters:

```
    select greatest(:start_date, trunc(add_months( :start_date, 3 * (level - 1)), 'Q')) as startmonth,
           least(:end_date, last_day(add_months( :start_date, 3 * (level - 1) + 2))) as endmonth
      from dual
connect by level <= trunc(months_between(trunc( :end_date, 'Q'), trunc( :start_date, 'Q'))) / 3 + 1;
```

Where :start_date and :end_date are your start and end dates.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the variant that's not limited to any specific range length:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(GREATEST(
         LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(:start_date, LEVEL - 2)) + 1,
         :start_date
       ), 'dd/mm/yyyy') AS StartMonth,
       TO_CHAR(LEAST(
         :end_date, 
         LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(:start_date, LEVEL - 1))
       ), 'dd/mm/yyyy') AS EndMonth
FROM dual
CONNECT BY LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(:start_date, LEVEL - 1)) <= LAST_DAY(:end_date);
```

EDIT: after fixing the start date range, it looks very much like the accepted answer, with different way of doing date arithmetic. And for quarterly, @GriffeyDog's usage of `TRUNC` is probably the best bet still.

Comment: My date starts with 3rd January and ends with 28th December.But your query gives it from 1st jan and ends with 31st December which doesn't fulfill my requirement..Seems like Barbaros got it right

Comment: Well it depends on whether you want to only list full months, or partial ones too. For the input of '03/01/2018', I don't think the '01/01/2018' to '31/01/2018' should be listed. Then again, it might have just been unclear requirements. Either way, you've got the general idea on how all these solutions have been made

Comment: That's because you're supposed to pass the date as date, not string. Can be changed to handle the date as string too, but I wanted to omit it for brevity

Comment: I mean the end date, pass it as to_date if your argument is string

Comment: @AlexSavitsky i've converted them to date but still your query gets wrong results : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/80ffe1/21

Comment: Yes, we've discussed it with OP already, seem like a misunderstanding with requirements. That's why I upvoted GriffeyDog's answer instead, he got this part right. I'll fix mine later, just so as not to have incorrect answers around

Answer (score 0):

Here is a CTE (Common Table Expression) that generates the monthly entries:

```
WITH
    aset
    AS
        (SELECT DATE '2018-01-03' start_month, DATE '2018-12-28' last_month
           FROM DUAL),
    bset (start_month, end_month, last_month)
    AS
        (SELECT start_month, LEAST (ADD_MONTHS (TRUNC (start_month, 'MM'), 1) - 1, last_month) end_month, last_month
           FROM aset
         UNION ALL
         SELECT ADD_MONTHS (TRUNC (start_month, 'MM'), 1)
              , LEAST (ADD_MONTHS (start_month, 2) - 1, last_month)
              , last_month
           FROM bset
          WHERE end_month < last_month)
SELECT start_month, end_month
  FROM bset;


START_MONTH END_MONTH
----------- ---------
03-JAN-18   31-JAN-18
01-FEB-18   02-MAR-18
01-MAR-18   31-MAR-18
01-APR-18   30-APR-18
01-MAY-18   31-MAY-18
01-JUN-18   30-JUN-18
01-JUL-18   31-JUL-18
01-AUG-18   31-AUG-18
01-SEP-18   30-SEP-18
01-OCT-18   31-OCT-18
01-NOV-18   30-NOV-18
01-DEC-18   28-DEC-18
```